# Javascript to php the same file

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have a problem. I need to get the value from a select tag then use it in php for my sql. Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label> ROOMS </label>
     <?php     
                echo "<select value= 'TRoom1' id ='TRoom1' class='form control'>";
                      echo "<option>Select Room Type</option>";
                       while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                       {

                          echo "<option>" . $row1['Room_type'] . "</option>";

                       }
                       echo "</select>";
                   ?>
```

this is for the sql command

```
         <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="container">
                <?php
                  $selectedValue = $_POST['TRoom1'];
            $sql = "SELECT  RoomNumber FROM rooms Where Room_type = '$selectedValue' ";
                  $result = mysql_query($sql);
                   echo "<select value= 'RoomNo' id ='RoomID' class='form-control'>";
                      echo "<option>Select Room Number</option>";
                       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                       {

                          echo "<option>" . $row['RoomNumber'] . "</option>";
                       }
                       echo "</select>";
                   ?>
```

TIA! :))

THis is the code ofor room type with its corresponding room number

```
                           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> ROOMS </label>
                    <?php

     echo "<select value= 'TRoom1' name ='TRoom1' id ='TRoom1' class='form-control'>";
                      echo "<option>Select Room Type</option>";
                       while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                       {

                          echo "<option>" . $row1['Room_type'] . "</option>";

                       }
                       echo "</select>";
                   ?>

                 </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <?php
                 $select_value=$_POST['selectedValue'];
          $sql = "SELECT  RoomNumber FROM rooms Where Room_type = '$select_value' ";
                  $result = mysql_query($sql);

                 echo "<select value= 'RoomNo' id ='RoomID' class='form-control'>";
                      echo "<option>Select Room Number</option>";
                       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                       {

                          echo "<option>" . $row['RoomNumber'] . "</option>";

                       }
                       echo "</select>";
                   ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: ON same page or call that page in form action ?

Comment: you can use ajax calls also

Comment: i already try that. but i always get an error on $_POST['TRoom1']. TRoom1 didnt recognize. undefined variable

Comment: can you paste your codes ?

Comment: that is my code for sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use name attribute for your select tag if u want to fetch the value in the php part and in the option u have to pass the value attibute.that value u will get in the php part.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

 <form action="a.php" method="post">
 <select name="selectname" id="someid" >
 <?php
 while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
 {
 ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $varible ?>"> <?php echo $row1['Room_type']; ?></option>

 <?php } ?>                
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

for php part:u can fetch value like this:
filename=a.php

```
<?php
$select_value=$_REQUEST['selectname'];
$sql1 = "SELECT  RoomNumber FROM rooms Where Room_type = '$select_Value' ";
$sql=mysql_result(mysql_query($sql1),0);
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: selectname :(

Comment: can u share the modified code please.and avoid exececuting queries in the same file u kept html .use separate php file and in form action specify the name of the php file.and use header to redirect to the form again when the data is succesfully submitted. i hope u are getting what i am saying.

Comment: you are getting undefined index error because the php part is not getting any value from ur html part.

Comment: yes i get that. i already use that with different file. how bout. if i use different file for my sql command. how can i get the result and put it back on the other file?

Comment: yes. thats the error. how can i fix that? without using form action?

Comment: Rishabh Raj-thank you! :) One more question. How can i put back the result from a.php and put it on a different select tag? :)

Comment: @JewelPicar use the concept of function in php.pass $sql in the function and use the same function in the html part also with same number of parameters.if u still have any doubt please let me know.enjoy coding.if i correctly answered your question dont forget to mark my answer as answered.

Comment: i am not suggesting u to use ajax as i think u r new in coding so that will be little messy for u.stick with php only for a while than u can experiment with ajax.

Comment: Thank you Rishabh Raj. :) I just really need to study hard for this project. Thank you. :) i'll just tell you if i encounter any problem. :)

Comment: Yes. I have no time also to study ajax, this project needs to submit tomorrow. BTW. thank you again. :)

Comment: anytime.i will be more than happy if i will proved to be helpful to u in coding.enjoy your weekend @JewelPicar :)

Comment: Hi Rishabh. :) can i ask another question? the a.php will automatically activated without submitting it? iam just confused. :)

Comment: hi @JewelPicar,both the files i.e. html and a.php are two different files.as u are already aware we are using action in our form.the action contains the name of the file where you want to send your form data for processing.so when you will click the submit button a query string of the form 'name=value' will form and this query string will go to ur a.php file where you have written the query.now u have to fetch the value using the php superglobal variables like $_REQUEST in our case.is it clear or shall i elaborate my points.let   me know.

Comment: @JewelPicar is your problem still exists?

Comment: im sorry. your code doesnt have a submit button. hehe. :) I will just put a submit button there. :) thank you again. :)

Comment: Is it posibble to have a multiple form in one file?

Comment: aah,that was a terrible silly mistake.i edited my code.please have a look.i am sorry if it caused u any problem.sometimes in hurry we overlook the important parts.thanks @JewelPicar for pointing to my mistake :)

Comment: ya we can have multiple forms in one file.no problem at all :)

Comment: if i use header the page will reload? What should i use if i dont want the page to be reload?

Comment: header will redirect to the specified location which u will mention in the parameter of the header.

Comment: i message you on fb. :) how can i retain the parent window without reloading it. i mean after the form submitted. then back to the parent window it keeps on reloading. It shouldnt reload to keep the data.

Comment: can u please show me one example of the scenario u are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
var Sel_val = document.getElementById('TRoom1').value;
```

`Sel_val` will be the selected value of that Dropdown.Better you use `ajax` in your case.If it is on the same page then you use `Form submit` method.

For the ajax first you need the target url and the value which you want to send..So try like

```
$.ajax({
    url : Url of the page at which the sql command will be there,
    type : 'POST',
    data : { Sel_val : Sel_val }
});
```

Then at your target file get the `Sel_val` via `POST` method.

Comment: what if my sql command is in the same page? do i need to put the same url?

Comment: i dont know y everybody is telling u to use ajax.as u said u just need the select value in the php part and then u want to use that value in ur mysql.have a look at my code i shared .i dont see use of ajax here.

Comment: i just need to get the value from select tag(html) then use it in php. the codes are in the same file. if i use post method the variable is undefine

Comment: Gautam3164 it doesnt work. the post method didnt recognize. :(

Answer (score 0):

Please google your doubts before posting here. There are plenty of example available. `mysql_query` is deprecated use `mysqli_` function

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <label> ROOMS </label>
  <?php     
            echo "<select id ='TRoom1' name ='TRoom1' class='form control'>";
                  echo "<option>Select Room Type</option>";
                   while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                   {

                      echo "<option value=".$row1['Room_type'].">" . $row1['Room_type'] . "</option>";

                   }
                   echo "</select>";
               ?>
```

If you are submitting your form as `post` you would get values as

```
 $sql = "SELECT Room_type, Rate, RoomNumber FROM rooms Where Room_type ='".$_POST['TRoom1']."' ";
```

Comment: @JewelPicar, See i have edited your code have updated ? ..I have added name ='TRoom1' . Please check the code again

Comment: i already add the name ='TRoom1' but there is still an error. This codes is in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the self action and  try this below code

```
        if($_POST){     
        $selectedValue = $_POST['TRoom1'];
        $sql = "SELECT  RoomNumber FROM rooms Where Room_type = '$selectedValue' ";
              $result = mysql_query($sql);
               echo "<select value= 'RoomNo' id ='RoomID' class='form-control'>";
                  echo "<option>Select Room Number</option>";
                   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                   {

                      echo "<option>" . $row['RoomNumber'] . "</option>";
                   }
                   echo "</select>";
        }
```